# Свойство -webkit-touch-callout

Tags: html, css

Привет...Встретил интересное свойство.
**-webkit-touch-callout**

Это свойство позволяет вам диктовать поведение браузера в момент тапа и удержания пальца на ссылке. По умолчанию в браузерах всплывает окно, содержащее информацию о ссылке. По умолчанию у этого свойства выставлено значение default, но установив значение none окошко с информацией всплывать не будет.

Создал тестовий пример в хроме но посмотреть эффект не удалось.При навердении на ссылку тултип появляется.

```
 a {-webkit-touch-callout: none;}
  <a href="#" title="foobar" >GOOOOO</a>
```

Comment: Так ведь свойство `-webkit-touch-callout` доступно только в браузере Safari на платформе iOS, начиная со 2-ой версии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте Safari.
[Здесь](http://cssdot.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_CSS/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_WebKit_Chrome_Safari/_webkit_touch_callout-i697.html) указано, что только этот браузер поддерживает сию технологию.

Comment: Спасибо,что уточнили.